# clear input type text when another input is cleared

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

so I have two input texts and when I clear one of them, I want another one to be automatically cleared too.

Is there any nice angular way to do this inside template?

```
<input type="text" ng-model="one" class="form-control">
<input type="text" ng-model="two" class="form-control">
```

these are the fields, when I clear first one, I want second to be cleared too

Comment: just use watch if one gets clear clear other one /

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Watch on first textbox for change, when it gets cleared, clear another also.

> Here is what you want.

```
$scope.$watch("one",function(newVal){
  if(newVal=="")
    $scope.two="";
})
```

Comment: @RobG Check the revision/history of the answer

Answer (score 0):

If u ve a form u can use the $setPristine(); method

example:

```
<button ng-click="mymagicform.$setPristine();">Submit</button>
```

doc link https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController